# Grouping a list of flat objects in a nested structure

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I have a List of objects A, where the object A has this form:

```
Class A {
private String a1;
private String a2;
private String a3;
private String a4;
private String a5;
private String a6;
}
```

I need to group this List first by a1 and then by a3, resulting in this way:
`Map<B, Map<C, List<D>>>`, where the object B has this form

```
Class B {
private String a1; 
private String a2;
}
```

and where the object C has this form

```
Class C {
private String a3;
private String a4;
}
```

and where the object D has this form

```
Class D {
private String a5;
private String a6;
}
```

Is this possibile with streams in Java 11? Any other ways to achieve this goal are welcome, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have these lombok annotations on your classes (It's fine if you don't have lombok - you can just add these boilerplate to your classes if you don't have them already):

```
@Getter
class A {
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
    private String a3;
    private String a4;
    private String a5;
    private String a6;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "a2")
class B {
    private String a1;
    private String a2;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "a4")
class C {
    private String a3;
    private String a4;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
class D {
    private String a5;
    private String a6;
}
```

Note that it is important that `B` and `C`'s `equals` and `hashCode` only depend on `a1` and `a3` respectively.

Then given `List<A> aList`, you can nest the `groupingBy` collectors like this, and at the very end, map each thing to a `D`.

```
var map = aList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> new B(x.getA1(), x.getA2()),
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            x -> new C(x.getA3(), x.getA4()),
            Collectors.mapping(
                x -> new D(x.getA5(), x.getA6()),
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )
    )
);
```

and `map` will be a `Map<B, Map<C, List<D>>>`.